# Can someone help me debug my tic tac toe game?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game using html, css, and javascript. I have managed to make some progress on it, but there are two bugs that I haven't been able to figure out no matter how hard I look.

The first one is that it won't take in an input on the last block (9). After I added the code for checking wins and ties it no longer worked.

The second one is that the AI starts playing on my second move, not on the first one. It must be a simple logic error, but I just don't see it.

Here's my code on repl.it:
https://repl.it/@julkothegu1/Yes

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a 0 vs 1 based issue.  Just change your HTML to this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='block' id='0'></td>
        <td class='block' id='1'></td>
        <td class='block' id='2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='block' id='3'></td>
        <td class='block' id='4'></td>
        <td class='block' id='5'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='block' id='6'></td>
        <td class='block' id='7'></td>
        <td class='block' id='8'></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like the question is both off-topic *and* caused by an off-by-one typo. Best to flag for closure instead of answering - these sorts of questions have no value for future readers

Comment: It seemed as though this person was just trying to get some help with their issue...I disagree. It was their first question they asked too, so thought it was crappy that everyone downvoted them.  Show some love.

Comment: See [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) (no) and [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) (no). Stack Overflow is not a help desk - it's a repository of *useful* questions and answers, of which this post is not. The question is objectively off-topic in at least two ways - surely that's downvote worthy

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed something as simple as that. 

I wasn't aware that my question was considered off-topic though. If I had the same problem and I found an answer like this I would definitely find it helpful, albeit simple. I don't see the problem in answering simple questions on a site that is supposed to be made for helping. I guess there is such a thing as a stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the array index as value for your ID. However, the array counting starts at 0 while your ID's start at 1.

This ends up that on the first play, the computes tries to play on id "0", which does not exists.

And when you click on the last element, there's also a missmatch between id and index.

To fix both problems, start your ID count on 0 at your HTML.

Comment: It looks like the question is both off-topic *and* caused by an off-by-one typo. Best to flag for closure instead of answering - these sorts of questions have no value for future readers